# Streamlit is Repeatedly Running a Loop When Entering Details

Tags: python, error-handling, streamlit

I have a Streamlit code that initially asks for the candidate's Full Name, Experience, and Language. Upon clicking the submit button, it displays three questions (Question 1, Question 2, Question 3). The issue arises when I enter an answer in the text box for Question 1. After that, when I attempt to enter an answer in the text box for Question 2, the page resets and starts from the beginning. How can I resolve this problem?

Here is the code

````
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def main():
    st.title('Employer Test')
    st.markdown('## Candidate Information')

    # Full Name Input
    full_name = st.text_input('Full Name')

    # Experience Dropdown
    experience = st.selectbox("Experience", ["Fresher"], index=0)
    
    # Language Dropdown
    language = st.selectbox("Language", ["Python"], index=0)

    # Button to start the test
    if st.button('Submit'):
        if full_name:
            run_python_test(full_name)

def run_python_test(full_name):
    st.title('Python Test')

    # Dummy test questions and answers
    questions = [
        {
            'question': 'What is the output of the following code?\n\n```python\nx = 5\nprint(x)\n```',
            'options': ['5', '10', '0', 'Error'],
            'correct_answer': '5'
        },
        {
            'question': 'Which of the following is a Python data type?',
            'options': ['List', 'Streamlit', 'GitHub', 'HTML'],
            'correct_answer': 'List'
        },
        {
            'question': 'What is the result of the expression 3 + 7 * 2?',
            'options': ['13', '20', '17', 'Error'],
            'correct_answer': '17'
        }
        # Add more questions here...
    ]

    total_questions = len(questions)
    score = 0
    answer = []

    for i, question_data in enumerate(questions):
        question = question_data['question']
        options = question_data['options']
        correct_answer = question_data['correct_answer']

        st.write(f'Question {i+1}: {question}')

        # Display options for each question
        answer.append(st.text_area(f"Enter answer for Question {i+1}", key=f"answer_{i}"))

    # Add a submit button
    if st.button("Submit Test", key="submit_test"):
        # Process the answers and calculate score
        for i, ans in enumerate(answer):
            if ans == questions[i]['correct_answer']:
                score += 1
            st.write(f"Question {i+1} Answer: {ans}")

    percentage_score = (score / total_questions) * 100

    if percentage_score >= 60:
        save_result(full_name, percentage_score)
        st.session_state['test_completed'] = True

def save_result(full_name, score):
    data = {'Full Name': [full_name], 'Score': [score]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('test_results.csv', index=False)
    st.write('Result saved successfully!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like session state was missing in your original code and so it's added.

The app now allow users to add their name and info, click on submit, then perform the 3 question quiz and submit. Afterwards, they can download the test results with a download button which was missing in the original code.

````py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.title('Employer Test')

if 'form_submitted' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['form_submitted'] = False

if 'test_completed' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['test_completed'] = False

def save_result(full_name, score):
    data = {'Full Name': [full_name], 'Score': [score]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('test_results.csv', index=False)
    csv = df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
    st.success('Result saved successfully!')
    st.download_button(
        label="Download test results",
        data=csv,
        file_name='test_results.csv',
        mime='text/csv',
    )

if not st.session_state['form_submitted']:
    st.markdown('## Candidate Information')

    with st.form(key='candidate_info'):
        # Full Name Input
        full_name = st.text_input('Full Name')

        # Experience Dropdown
        experience = st.selectbox("Experience", ["Fresher"], index=0)

        # Language Dropdown
        language = st.selectbox("Language", ["Python"], index=0)

        # Button to start the test
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button('Submit')
        if submit_button:
            st.session_state['form_submitted'] = True
            st.session_state['full_name'] = full_name

if st.session_state['form_submitted'] and not st.session_state['test_completed']:
    st.title('Python Test')

    # Dummy test questions and answers
    questions = [
        {
            'question': 'What is the output of the following code?\n\n```python\nx = 5\nprint(x)\n```',
            'options': ['5', '10', '0', 'Error'],
            'correct_answer': '5'
        },
        {
            'question': 'Which of the following is a Python data type?',
            'options': ['List', 'Streamlit', 'GitHub', 'HTML'],
            'correct_answer': 'List'
        },
        {
            'question': 'What is the result of the expression 3 + 7 * 2?',
            'options': ['13', '20', '17', 'Error'],
            'correct_answer': '17'
        }
        # Add more questions here...
    ]

    total_questions = len(questions)
    score = 0
    answer = []

    for i, question_data in enumerate(questions):
        question = question_data['question']
        options = question_data['options']
        correct_answer = question_data['correct_answer']

        st.write(f'Question {i+1}: {question}')

        # Display options for each question
        answer.append(st.text_area(f"Enter answer for Question {i+1}", key=f"answer_{i}"))

    # Add a submit button
    if st.button("Submit Test", key="submit_test"):
        # Process the answers and calculate score
        for i, ans in enumerate(answer):
            if ans == questions[i]['correct_answer']:
                score += 1
            st.write(f"Question {i+1} Answer: {ans}")
        
        percentage_score = (score / total_questions) * 100

        if percentage_score >= 60:
            save_result(st.session_state['full_name'], percentage_score)
            st.session_state['test_completed'] = True
````

Hope this helps!

More info on Session state in Streamlit can be found in the following resources:

- https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state
- https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state